# How can i store value in array get from slice

Tags: javascript

```
var count = i;
var container = finalvaluearr[i];
var gg[i] = container.slice(0, count);
```

Here i am trying to store the value but error show in console Unexpected token [ 
How can i do it any solution. i am doing with the help of forloop

Comment: `gg[i]` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: I am using it for Temporary

Answer (score 0):

Define your `gg` object first:

```
var count = i;
var container = finalvaluearr[i];
var gg = {};
gg[i] = container.slice(0, count);
```